# Determine node.js version from Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I know I can determine the version of Meteor with `Meteor.release` but is there a simple way to determine the node version Meteor is running on top of from a running Meteor app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
process.version
```

Meteor is built on top of Node.js and hence you've got access to the full [Node API](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version).